# Access "this" from within anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, this

OK, this may sound ultra-simple, but since it's the very first time I'm getting really serious with JavaScript/jQuery, I want to know what's the best way to go about it.

**So, here's the situation:**

```
var someClass = function()
{
    var someProperty;

    /*********************************
     Initialisation
     *********************************/

    this.construct = function(options){

        this.someProperty = "someValue";

        $("#someDiv").click(function(){
            // I want to access "this" (= the someClass object) here
        });

    }
}

var theObj = new someClass();
```

Now, here's what: Given that, in my particular case, `theObj` is just a single (global) object, I could obviously do :

```
$("#someDiv").click(function(){
     console.log(theObj.someProperty);
});
```

But I most definitely do not *like* it - and there must be a more elegant/object-oriented-friendly way.

---

So, how would you go about it?

Comment: A tip: Functions can acces the variables in all outer scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `bind` to keep the same context:

```
$("#someDiv").click((function(){
        // same this as externally
}).bind(this));
```

Or you can define a variable in the closure :

```
var obj = this;
$("#someDiv").click(function(){
        // your this is obj
});
```

Or if using Firefox (and soon other browsers) you can use an arrow function :

```
$("#someDiv").click(() => {
        // same this as externally
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not using the `.prototype` to add methods, and are instead creating them as privileged methods within the class, just use an additional variable in the constructor's scope that refers to the object:

```
var someClass = function() {

    var self = this;

    ...

};
```

This allows you to preserve the normal jQuery semantics that `this` refers to the clicked element, whilst making `self` available to refer to the wrapping object.  For this semantic preservation reason I would specifically recommend against using `.bind(this)`.

Regarding your final proposed "solution" of just using `theObj` inside the callback - you should also *never* refer to an object by its own name from inside itself, since those names are not under your control and may change.  It *might* be safe in your current code, but it's a nightmare for code maintenance and code isolation.

Answer (score 3):

There're many approaches. Yours is one and it's one of most simpler and effective approaches, and as far as I know, it implies less performance penalties (it uses closures).

Other approaches:

#### *.bind(this)*.

`bind` changes the meaning of `this` inside the scope of a given function. If you do the following, click handler this keyword will be the outter `this` reference:

```
 // This will bind outter "this" as the object referenced by 
 // inner this
 $("#someDiv").click(function(){
      console.log(this.someProperty);
 }.bind(this));
```

#### *.call(this, arg1, argN)*.

`call` defines the reference of `this` within the called function. The first parameter is the `this` reference to be `this` in the called function scope. Next parameters are callable function arguments (if the function has them). *This isn't for the click handler use case*.

There're some edge cases where you would want to use `call`. For example, if you want to route an event in some custom way and the event handler receive a custom context:

```
 var that = this;

 $("#someDiv").click(function(){
      // Some handler function from the outter scope. It will have a "this"
      // reference to the outter "this" object reference
      someHandlerFunction.call(that, { currentElement: this, timeStamp: Date.now() });
 });
```

#### *.apply(this, [arg1, argN])*.

Same as `call`, function arguments are given in an array instead of as actual function arguments separated by a comma like a regular function call. *Also, not applicable in your use case*.

## Conclusion

Prefered approach: yours. `bind`/`call`/`apply` approach is less performant and it has a big drawback if you use in DOM event handlers: **you lose the standard `this` meaning as defined by DOM - the reference of the DOM element which originated the event -**.

Use bind in other edge cases, where `this` would mean `window` JavaScript object, and you want to avoid the *closure approach*.

Comment: @Alnitak Not relevant, that's why I said **This isn't for the click handler use case.**, but I want to show OP how `this` reference can be manipulated in other use cases...

Comment: so you did - IMHO it probably confuses the answer somewhat.

Comment: @Alnitak Now I provided a possible use case of `call(...)`, which is used in KnockoutJS some times.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, and not only in KO, I've required that many times in other contex.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind` or save a reference to `this`:

```
$("#someDiv").click((function() {
  console.log(this.someProperty);
}).bind(this));
```

or

```
var that = this;

$("#someDiv").click((function(){
   console.log(that.someProperty);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For reasons of being fair, since @dystroy's answer was some seconds faster, this is the one I'm going to select. :-)